# HTML Loading Images: Is my algorithm producing too much traffic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

today I've developed an algorithm which loads different images into a simple gallery. The script is creating image tags to "buffer" the images into. Then, JQuery is used to determine, whether the image finished loading. If so, it hides my loading_animation.gif, removes the image tag and shows a div tag with the image set as it's background-image. Basically I'm using the img tag to be able to use JQuery's .load() function. The div tag is used to display the image properly.

My question is: Is the image loaded twice from the net or is it cached by the browser? When I watched my script working, it seemed like the images got cached, but is it always the case? If people disable caching they'd load the images twice, wouldn't they?

Here's my code:

CSS

```
.imagewrapper .imageholder {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
.imagewrapper .loading_animation {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(versuchsordner/img/loading_anim.gif);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    float: left;
}
.image_preloader {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.imagewrapper .image_preloader').load(function() {

        $(this).siblings('.loading_animation').fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).siblings('.image_preloader').remove();
            $(this).siblings('.imageholder').fadeIn();
        });
    });         
});
```

PHP/HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
        <?php
        $parser = new Parser("","basti",25);
        $entry_id = 87;
        $album = $parser->selectAlbumByEntryId($entry_id, "all");
        foreach ($album->pictures as $picture) {
            ?>
            <div class="imagewrapper">
                <img class="image_preloader" src="<?php echo $picture->originalPath; ?>" />
                <div class="imageholder" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $picture->originalPath; ?>');"></div>
                <div class="loading_animation"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea should work fine provided some conditions exist:

- the server must set an expiration date (that is not in the past)
- client-side caching must be enabled and nothing interferes with it

**Edit:** I think this method is better because it goes in line with the user's choice: if the user disables caching, than s/he *wants to see the resources each time* - and I think one should honour the user choice in this case. Don't forget that the user might be the developer himself checking out how the website loads the first time when things are not cached - something I do a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think its not the best approach.

If you like pre-loading images (that can be very tricky), you should use JS and declare

```
var img1023 = new Image();
```

If people disabled caching, well, its gonna download every time from server. But most users will get it in the cache (depends more on the cache tool installed on the web server.)

Comment: Can JS check weather caching is enabled? So I could say: use method 1 when it's enabled, use method 2 when it's not

Comment: If people disable caching and this "breaks", you're just honouring their choice...so I wouldn't call this a bug, but a feature. In fact, because of this I think his approach is in fact better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203509/how-to-check-if-browser-caching-disabled

Comment: So if I understood you right, you're saying I should "cache" the image in a JS variable instead of HTML? And later on pass that variable to my background-image of that div?

Comment: Well its very important to understand: Web page is simple words. then browser interpret images, videos, audio, and so on as "resources" , JS is only script, a chain of commands to do commands. for all web page functioning right, there is an Object that called `window` that contain varibles and information including the DOM. when JS script declare new Image, its not his image but part of the complete web-page. Coprando? =)

Comment: @JustBasti Maybe you didn't read my answer or my comment above, so let me say it again; this answer is probably not the one you should work with.

Comment: @Christian I see .. I thought you were saying his apprach was better. I just tried doing it his way but decided not to go further since my code would look very badly. Thanks for your answer, I get your idea now.